# Heatmap colors in R

Tags: r, matlab, heatmap, colorbar

I am trying to replicate the pictured color palette [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIp0K.png) from Matlab in r.

This is the code I have so far:

levelplot(rdm[,nrow(rdm):1], col.regions =colorRampPalette(c("Blue", "green", "yellow")) )

But the colors are not quite right.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One potential solution is to use the [colorRamps package](https://rdrr.io/cran/colorRamps/), e.g. with `blue2green2red()`

```r
install.packages("colorRamps")
library(colorRamps)
image(matrix(1:400, 20), col = blue2green2red(500)[100:400])
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Or, with `matlab.like()`:

```
image(matrix(1:1000, 20), col = matlab.like(100)[10:70])
```

[image: example_2.png]

These aren't exactly the same as your image, but I think they're pretty close. Does this solve your problem?

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks for including all the required details in your question :)